# SSRS How to change export Excel Tab Name (2) when ther is no group name

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using "Break to new page" for every Group value in my report. And I set the TAB names of the excel export to be the Group-Value itself. This works fine for the data within a group.
But on the last TAB there is the overall "TOTAL" which is in no group.

So excel just takes the last groupname it finds and addes a "**(2)**" at the end of the TAB-name.
[image]

I tried to set a fixed name for ISNOTHING() or IIF(Value=""...) but it did not work.

Does anyone have an idea? Please let me know and thak you in advance!

Here is the data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PerPage](
    [VendorDim] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NULL,
    [SomeText] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[PerPage] ([VendorDim], [Amount], [SomeText]) VALUES ('AR', 1, 'a')
INSERT [dbo].[PerPage] ([VendorDim], [Amount], [SomeText]) VALUES ('AR', 2, 's')
INSERT [dbo].[PerPage] ([VendorDim], [Amount], [SomeText]) VALUES ('BR', 3, 'f')
INSERT [dbo].[PerPage] ([VendorDim], [Amount], [SomeText]) VALUES ('BR', 4, 'g')
INSERT [dbo].[PerPage] ([VendorDim], [Amount], [SomeText]) VALUES ('AH', 5, 'h')
INSERT [dbo].[PerPage] ([VendorDim], [Amount], [SomeText]) VALUES ('AH', 6, 'j')
INSERT [dbo].[PerPage] ([VendorDim], [Amount], [SomeText]) VALUES ('AH', 7, 'k')
```

Here is how the Report is built:
[image]

When exporting to excel for every Tab it take the name of the Group VendorDIM. But the Total is not in any group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will remove the total from the grouped Tablix.
Add a new Tablix page with the summed up Totals.
And give it a "Total" Name.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to edit your question and show your report design along with details of your row groups and their relevant properties.

However, you said

> "there is the overall "TOTAL" which is in no group"

Are you sure this is true? I would expect this to be in a parent group, in which case you can set the page name in the parent group's properties in the same way you have done for the other row group.

If this does not help, share the design, it's hard to help without more info.

Comment: I updated the Question with more informations. I hope it is now clearer what my problem is.